Why are the child processes not running?
Below is a script that reflects the critical part of a larger application. The outline is:

I'm consuming data from an API which here is simulated by iterating over an array of ints.
The code runs the data coming off the API through a long(ish) calculation which here is simulated with process_the_data.
Once done, the output is written to a database here simulated as write_to_sql.

I need to speed up the ingestion so I'm trying to parallelize the process_the_data calls which is the biggest bottleneck. The intent is for the 3 child processes to write their results into a single Queue to be written out to a database.
The two primary errors I'm getting are: EOFError, BrokenPipe. But after writing this simplified version I think I've misunderstood something about the multiprocessing module and/or Queue class because the output_q is not ever written to.
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def process_the_data(in_q, out_q):
    while True:
        data = in_q.get(block=True)
        time.sleep(random.choice([1,2,3]))
        out_q.put_nowait(data + 1)

def write_to_sql(n):
    print(n)

multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
input_q = mgr.Queue(maxsize=5)
output_q = mgr.Queue()

input_data = range(100)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_the_data, args=(input_q, output_q))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_the_data, args=(input_q, output_q))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_the_data, args=(input_q, output_q))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

for n in input_data:
     # realized this loop is wrong but doesn’t change the behavior
     while not input_q.full():
         input_q.put(n)

     while not output_q.empty():
         write_to_sql(output_q.get(block=False))

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()

print('finished')


This should better use a multiprocessing.Pool which handles most things (especially the queueing) automatically.

You have in your main process:
for n in input_data:
     # realized this loop is wrong but doesn’t change the behavior
     while not input_q.full():
         input_q.put(n)

     while not output_q.empty():
         write_to_sql(output_q.get(block=False))

The input queue has a size of 5 so the first time through this while loop you will be putting the value 0 on to the input queue at least 5 times before the queue is "full", possibly more times if the child processes get a chance to retrieve some of these values making the queue no longer full. You have here a non-deterministic race condition. After you have put your 5 plus values on the queue, your retrieve from the output queue until the queue is empty, which may be immediately and so you might be retrieving no results the first time through the results. On the final iteration through the loop the output queue might at this moment be empty and you will never retrieve anything. This is another race condition.
For debugging purposes I have added some print statements to see what is actually happening as follows:
def process_the_data(in_q, out_q):
    while True:
        data = in_q.get(block=True)
        print('get in')
        time.sleep(random.choice([1,2,3]))
        print('put out', data + 1)
        out_q.put_nowait(data + 1)

...

for n in input_data:
    # realized this loop is wrong but doesn’t change the behavior
    while True:
        print('testing input queue is full')
        if input_q.full():
            print('input queue is full')
            break
        print('put in', n)
        input_q.put(n)


    while True:
        print('testing output queue has data')
        if output_q.empty():
            print('output queue is empty')
            break
        print('get out')
        write_to_sql(output_q.get(block=False))


print('while loop completed')

The output is:
testing input queue is full
put in 0
testing input queue is full
put in 0
testing input queue is full
get in
put in 0
testing input queue is full
put in 0
testing input queue is full
put in 0
get in
testing input queue is full
get in
put in 0
testing input queue is full
put in 0
testing input queue is full
put in 0
testing input queue is full
input queue is full
testing output queue has data
output queue is empty
testing input queue is full
input queue is full
testing output queue has data
output queue is empty

... Duplicated lines omitted

testing input queue is full
input queue is full
testing output queue has data
output queue is empty
testing input queue is full
input queue is full
testing output queue has data
output queue is empty
while loop completed
put out 1
get in
put out 1
get in
put out 1
put out 1
get in
get in
put out 1
get in
put out 1
put out 1
put out 1

At this point the everything hangs without having seen even a single 'get out' printed and thus we have no calls to write_to_sql being made. The while loop has been fully iterated without a single result being retrived. Now the main process waits for the child processes to terminate, which will never occur because they loop forever.
Remove the race conditions with:
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def process_the_data(in_q, out_q):
    while True:
        data = in_q.get(block=True)
        if data is None:  # Sentinel value
            break
        #time.sleep(random.choice([.1,.2,.3]))
        out_q.put(data + 1)

def write_to_sql(n):
    print(n)

multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
input_q = mgr.Queue(maxsize=5)
output_q = mgr.Queue()

input_data = range(100)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_the_data, args=(input_q, output_q))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_the_data, args=(input_q, output_q))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_the_data, args=(input_q, output_q))

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

for n in input_data:
    input_q.put(n)

for _ in range(3):  # The number of child processes
    input_q.put(None)  # Sentinel value

for _ in range(len(input_data)):
    write_to_sql(output_q.get(block=True))

p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()

print('finished')

But I would suggest that you replace the managed queue instances with the more efficient multiprocessing.Queue instances.
